# EF Core: Include over multiple levels of m:n Relations

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following tables.

[image: DB Tables]

One use is member of multiple roles and one role can have multiple UseCases.

In my user entity I need the distinct list of UseCases the user has access to.

```
public class AppConfigUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }

    public List<UseCase> UseCases { get; set; } // <= distinct list from m:n relations
}
```

Is it possible to configure the entities in a way that I can simply query the User entity including the UseCases?

```
var users = _dbContext.Users.Include(_ => _.UseCases);
```

Comment: As far as I know - no. The "best" you can do is something like `Users.Include(u => u.UseRoles).ThenInclude(r => r.UseCases)`. Unless you are willing to introduce a view.

Answer (score 1):

You should write query, just `Include` will load to much data:

```cs
var useCases = 
    from u in _dbContext.Users
    from r in u.UserRoles
    from uc in r.UseCases
    where u.UserId == userId
    select uc;

useCases = useCases.Distinct();
```